# How to subscribe for changing of url parameters with pagerjs?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, pagerjs

I want to implement grid paging with pagerjs library. I found how to read parameters from javascript code. With html

```
<div data-bind="page: { id: 'clients', params: {'page':1}, title: 'Clients', withOnShow: requireVM('clientsList') }">
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'clientsSearch' }" id="clients-list" class="clientsSearch"></div>
</div>
```

I successfuly bind template and viewmodel. Incide viewmodel I can read value of page parameter with code

```
pager.activePage$().ctx.page
```

The page property is observable. I tried to subscribe to it with code

```
pager.activePage$().ctx.page.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    debugger;
});
```

I made button for navigating to next page

```
<li data-bind="css: { disabled: isLastPage() }">
    <a class="btn" data-bind="page-href: {path: '/start/clients', params: { page: parseInt(currentPage()) + 1 }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</li>
```

It changes Url nicely but pager.activePage$().ctx.page.subscribe doesn't actualy fire.

I need some approach to notify viewmodel about parameters changes. How can I accomplish it?

Comment: Can you please provide a small jsfiddle? Can't you just add a `click` binding to detect page change?

Comment: I was strugling to make it work in jsfiddle and found solution. I subscribe to pager.onNoMatch event. It's actualy fires after last route found and page is opened. So, I check page.route.length inside pager.onNoMatch and notify viewModel in current context. I don't like to use click binding because it's not universal approach.